# Are questions about IDE configuration for a test framework on-topic?

Tags: discussion

There are a number of general tasks a test IDE should be capable of, like:

- launching test cases/ test suites
- debugging test cases
- possibility to easily maintain and manage test suites
- refactor support, etc.

Configuring some of the above mentioned items are not always trivial in a specific IDE (e.g. VS Code or Atom which are highly customizable) for a specific framework.

In such cases is it OK to ask the question here or it should be posted on Stack Overflow instead?